# How to include form page inside Tab in JSF

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets

In my JSF page I have Tab. Inside the Tab I have Datatable and button. My requirement is When I click the button inside the tab an new form page should be displayed and Datatable should be hidden and in that form page after filling all details when I click save button again datatable should appear. Iam using JSF2.0,PrimeFaces 3.2,DK 1.5 and Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2):

Put them both in the view and use the `rendered` attribute to switch between the components.

E.g.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not bean.showForm}">
        <h:dataTable ... />
        ...
        <h:commandButton value="Submit table" action="#{bean.submitTable}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.showForm}">
        <h:inputText ... />
        ...
        <h:commandButton value="Submit form" action="#{bean.submitForm}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

with this in a `@ViewScoped` bean:

```java
private boolean showForm;

public void submitTable() {
    // ...
    showForm = true;
}

public void submitForm() {
    // ...
    showForm = false;
}
```

Comment: Issue 1:-                                                               I have 4 tabs in Tabview. In one Tab I have datatable and many commandbutton. When i click on any command button. I believe the page is refreshing and its directing to firsttab. How to overcome this.

Comment: Issue 2:-                                                            By default primefaces <p:commandbutton > are bulit in Ajax function right. In my application we delibertly making ajax = false then only server side communication happens when I remove ajax=false nothing happens. 
Would you explain me why this thing happening.

Comment: If you have a new question, press "Ask Question" button. The current one is already answered.